# Lua socket.http sink parameter

Tags: sockets, https, lua, luasocket

I'm trying to communicate with my servers from Lua to authenticate a user. This is what my request function looks like:

```
function http.send(url)
    local req = require("socket.http")
    local b, c, h = req.request{
        url = url,
        redirect = true
    }
    return b
end
```

However, I noticed that the data is discarded because I did not provide the `sink` parameter. I want to be able to return the downloaded data as a whole string, not download to a file/table. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ltn12.sink.table`](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/ltn12.html#sink.table) to collect the results into a given table piece by piece. Then you can use `table.concat` to get the resulting string.

Example of use from the documentation of `ltn12.sink`:

```
-- load needed modules
local http = require("socket.http")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")

-- a simplified http.get function
function http.get(u)
  local t = {}
  local status, code, headers = http.request{
    url = u,
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(t)
  }
  return table.concat(t), headers, code
end
```